# link to css file do not work in chrome and opera and work in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, opera

I have the following link to css file

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="pokemonroad logo" width="270px" height="135px" /></a>
    <img src="images/banner.png"  class="banner"/>
</body>
```

its was working fine, but now can not see css/stylesheet.css in all browsers.

Comment: [A `<link>` tag can occur only in the head element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Notes)

Comment: is there any other code in your file?

Comment: I just created a file with the code works fine....

Comment: When you right-click in Chrome and choose "Inspect Element" do you see the stylesheet listed in the `Sources` tab?

Comment: when I inspect no stylesheet is listed. and now also not working in firefox. this is some serious issue in the code.

Comment: check the directory path

Comment: You can just paste the full path to the stylesheet in your browser and see if it comes up...it may show you an error that will give you some insight. Example: `http://localhost/css/stylesheet.css` Another good choice is to go to the Network tab on Chrome developer tools and refresh the page. See if you see any red lines.

Comment: the full path to css gave the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '²Ü¥zÈ^z×,' at line 5

Comment: Wow, SQL errors on a path to css...that looks like you have some problems on the server to address. Sorry Muhammad.

Comment: @PaulOliver what kind of problem on server? I can login and also other queries are running.

Comment: /post_images/249_Lugia_02.png path to an image also have such error.

Comment: I'm not sure. You shouldn't have SQL errors on a CSS file--the server normally shouldn't hit the SQL database to serve up a text-only file like that. I wonder if you have a security check that hits the database for every page request? That could be the problem, but without more information I can't help much more than that.

Comment: @PaulOliver css file have no security check. here is my css: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsk3iyb7dz3am8q/stylesheet.css

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51989/discussion-between-paul-oliver-and-muhammad)

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome dev tools (right-click and choose "Inspect Element") to look for the stylesheet in the **Sources** tab. If you don't see it, go to the **Network** tab in Chrome Dev Tools and refresh the page. Look for red text that would indicate a failed file load.

That said, here's how you would typically add your stylesheet to your page if all is working well. First, you should put `type="text/css"` as an attribute on there. And more importantly, put it in the head of the document:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="pokemonroad logo" width="270px" height="135px" /></a>
    <img src="images/banner.png"  class="banner"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: na thats not the issue i just checked it by creating a file on my local system.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is missing `type` and `media`
the directory where you have yur CSS file must be a subdirectory of the file where you are calling

[image: Css]

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" media="screen, print"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="pokemonroad logo" width="270px" height="135px" /></a>
    <img src="images/banner.png"  class="banner"/>
</body>
```

Comment: type and media attributes aren't necessary on <link> elements.

Comment: yes my files are in main folder, and stylesheet.css is in css folder.

Comment: @WearFox when I put the full path for css/stylesheet.css it gave error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '²Ü¥zÈ^z×,' at line 5

Comment: MySQL? ammm MySQL  is another kind of code... can you put all your code... the error is not in the HTML file... maybe is in the others files that you are calling